# Анимация нажатия на кнопку и обработка onhover

Tags: android, button

Нужно сделать такую анимацию, как на картинке. Как можно добиться такого же эффекта, когда мы нажимаем на кнопку, выделяется одна буква, мы начинаем вести пальцем и с такой же анимацией выделяются другие. Как только мы отпускаем палец, все кнопки возвращаются в исходное состояние.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался реализовать подобное путём создания нескольких `textview`, а в `setOnClickListener` ставил изменение цвета, но это не позволяет добиться такой же анимации. Как отслеживать движения onhover, если какая-то кнопка уже была нажата?

Буду рад любой помощи, любой подсказке к решению задачи.

Comment: Работайте в сторону кастомных View. Там есть возможность отслеживать касание. А уже зная координаты, можно задать нужное поведение.